# Child activity return button vs finish()

Tags: android, android-activity

I noticed this: I have a parent activity A which opens child activity B with `startActivity(intent)`. In the activity B if I will `finish()` this activity in some way the parent activity will be loaded again from initial state, but if I will hit the back keyboard button I will be returned to activity A as in the state in which I left it.

Here is an example of how I am finishing activity B:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
   switch (item.getItemId()) 
   {
     case android.R.id.icon:
        finish();
        return true;
     default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }
}
```

Here is how I open activity B from activity A:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(thisActivity, toActivity);
startActivity(intent);
```

And here is the Manifest XML:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.evapp.activities.A"
    android:label="@string/A" >
</activity>
<activity
    android:name="com.evapp.activities.B"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:label="@string/B"
    android:parentActivityName="com.evapp.activities.A"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

    <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.evapp.activities.A" />
</activity>
```

Can someone please explain me the deference between `finish()` and return?

Comment: Are you overriding `onBackPressed`?

Comment: It should have the same effect ideally. Can you show where you are finishing it and the relevant related code?

Comment: Yes @Shobhit Puri, I have updated the question.

Comment: Do you override onActivityResult in Activity A? There should be no difference. However, Android can control lifetime its own ways, so you need to handle various cases. Also, hitting "finish" will return a value set as resultCode, while hitting the "back" button will return a "cancel" status (that's the only actual difference I can think of).

Comment: I am not overriding `onActivityResult`.

Comment: Have you overriden the `onKeyDown()` method?

Comment: Are you using fragments in your activities?

Comment: Yes I am using fragments @LukaCiko. No I am not using `onKeyDown()` @NKN.

Comment: Why do you have the parent activity specified in the manifest? Are you using `NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask()`? How are you creating the fragments in your activity B? We are not talking about the action bar up button, right?

Comment: I don't know what is `NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask()`. As I said in my question, I am using the icon (which appears with small arrow left, let to it) to go back to activity A. I am using fragment dialogs in fragment B. Some thing like this: `dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "some_dialog_fragment");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `finish()` and pressing the back button is not exactly the same when you are using fragments. If we check the source code of an Android `Activity`, we can see that it doesn't simply call `finish()` immediately, but calls it's `FragmentManagers`'s `popBackStackImmediate()` method before that.

```
/**
 * Called when the activity has detected the user's press of the back
 * key.  The default implementation simply finishes the current activity,
 * but you can override this to do whatever you want.
 */
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (!mFragments.popBackStackImmediate()) {
        finish();
    }
}
```

What `popBackState()` does is it removes the latest fragment from the back stack. Immediate simply means that it does it immediately instead of asynchronously. It returns false only when no fragment was removed - in that case `finish()` will be called.

I am not sure why your first activity seems to be reinitialized when calling `finish()`. In the case that you really get back to your first activity, it's `onResume()` method should get executed which might change it's appearance. To fully understand what's going on, we should see how you are creating your fragments and what happens in the `onResume()` method.

Comment: I am not using (yet) `onResume` but I will add the code which opens activity B.

Answer (score 1):

Pressing the back button and calling finish() should have exactly the same behavior provided you are not overriding onBackPressed.

When activity B is started from Activity A, the following events take place:

- Activity A will be paused (but not destroyed as long as sufficient resources are available)
- Activity B will be created and resumed

On calling finish() or pressing the back button from activity B, the following events will take place:

- Activity B will be paused
- Activity A will be resumed
- Activity B will be destroyed

Activity A is not created again but resumed. (unless it was destroyed due release resources).

You can verify the same with the following sample application.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.activitytest;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "MainActivity created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Button launchChild = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLaunchChild);
    launchChild.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
              Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ChildActivity.class);
              //myIntent.putExtra("key", value); //Optional parameters
              startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "MainActivity resumed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "MainActivity paused", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onPause();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "MainActivity destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
}
```

ChildActivity.java

```
package com.example.activitytest;

public class ChildActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_child);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Child created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Button finish = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFinish);
    finish.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Child resumed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Child paused", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onPause();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Child destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnLaunchChild"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/launch_child" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_child.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnFinish"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/finish" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.activitytest"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.activitytest.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.activitytest.ChildActivity">
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```